# porque no puedo meter un console.log de mi estado dentro de bcrypt.compare en react native?

Tags: react-native

```
bcrypt.compare(guess, password, function(err, res) {
          if(res) {
            console.log(this.state.algo);
          }
        });
```

No puedo hacer el console.log estoy corriendo la app con expo, en la pantalla me devuelve Something went wrong.

Comment: Tambien no puedo asignar un valor a variables.

Comment: En la función de compare (bcrypt), esta sucediendo un error, por lo cual nunca entrará a la condición: if(res) , ya que  es falso... Para tener mayor información del error puede realizar lo siguiente: **if(err) { console.log(err)}**,

Comment: O puedes capturar con un try y catch: try{ bcrypt.compare(...)} catch(err){console.log(err);}

Answer (score 0):

```
bcrypt.compare(guess, password, function(err, res) {
      if(res) {
        console.log(this.state.algo);
      }
    });
```

El problema era que tenia que hacer una funcion flecha.

```
bcrypt.compare(guess, password,(err, res)=> {
      if(res) {
        console.log(this.state.algo);
      }
    });
```